# google app invites(beta) not working in android 2.3.6

Tags: android, google-app-invites

Google App Invites(Beta) is not working in android 2.3.6 devices.
I tried out in a 4 devices of different versions & it failed only in 2.3.6.
Kindly point me to resources to resolve this error!

Below is the stacktrace

```
06-16 08:49:13.939    6396-6396/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.appinvite.AppInviteActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.android.gms.appinvite.ui.widget.g.<init>(SourceFile:167)
        at com.google.android.gms.appinvite.ui.widget.s.b(SourceFile:80)
        at com.google.android.gms.appinvite.ui.widget.d.a(SourceFile:76)
        at com.google.android.gms.appinvite.ui.context.h.a(SourceFile:409)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.b(SourceFile:1786)
        at android.support.v4.app.s.a(SourceFile:953)
        at android.support.v4.app.s.a(SourceFile:1136)
        at android.support.v4.app.a.run(SourceFile:739)
        at android.support.v4.app.s.h(SourceFile:1499)
        at android.support.v4.app.l.onStart(SourceFile:548)
        at com.google.android.gms.appinvite.AppInviteActivity.onStart(SourceFile:270)
```

Comment: What version of google play services are they running?

Comment: google play services version 7.5